# Xamarin apk on Blackberry (>= 10.2.1)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, blackberry-10

To convert a native Android .apk to a Blackberry .bar does not seem to be a problem.

However, I have an Android .apk (API 15) that I implemented using Xamarin. I am able to convert the file to a .bar file using the BB10 Sideloading Tool, but when I run the app on the Blackberry simulator, I get the error messages:

```
android_update_LD_LIBRARY_PATH not found; .so dependencies will not work
```

and later

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library cannot be found at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:361)
```

etc...

I am not really sure what steps can fix this errors.

- Is it basically possible to run Xamarin-created .apk-files on Blackberry?
- Would it maybe help to turn on the switch "Bundle assemblies into native code" in the Android Build options? For this, I would have to upgrade to Enterprise, but if it helps...

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure Xamarin works with building your code as a native (as in NDK) library for Android, and a small Java glue to load and run the code from this library.

Two things to note here: the simulator runs a x86 instruction set, when your library is probably built for ARM. Won't work.

For a real device, you'll have to check that every library needed by yours is present on a BB10 device, which is not guaranteed as far as I understand: http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/android_native_support.html